# How do I control for a confounding variable with this distribution?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, confounding

The short version of my question is: How is it possible to control for a confounding variable that has a Dirichlet distribution?

Suppose I have electoral and census data for a large set of cities. In this simplified example, say, there are two parties (Liberal and Conservative), and that someone is either college educated or not. I would like to test for correlation between  College Education and voting for the Liberal across all my cities. However I also have the income distribution per quintile, and want to control for this in my analysis. So the data looks something like:

```
City        Liberal Conservative CollegeEducated    Income Distribution
Springfield 55      45           61                  15 33 37 10 5
Shelbyville 38      62           43                  10 31 42 10 7
...
Capitol     70      30           57                  12 33 40 10 5
```

If my confounding variable were categorical I could maybe perform an elaboration analysis, but here I don't know what is valid. Any advice? Let me know if any of this needs clarification.

Comment: I don't see the point why do you need to control for a confounding variable with Dirichlet distribution.

Comment: This Dirichlet distribution is confusing to me. It is referring to the income distribution? Why should this distribution, whether it is Dirichlet or not, matter for the analysis?

Comment: This topic (with race instead of education) is surprisingly current in January 2024, since papers like “The Effect of Black Congressional Representation on Political Participation” have been in the news, and their ecological inferences have been criticized as logically inconsistent. Meanwhile the OP was ahead of their time to ask about educational polarization in 2011, years before the 2016 US election made it a prominent topic.

Comment: The distribution of the variable isn't what matters, just adjust for each of the 5 proportions. The interpretation of the other covariates is expected change in the % voting conservative comparing zipcodes having the same distribution of income.

Answer (score 2):

It's an interesting problem.
I'm assuming that all values are percentages,
e.g. that in Springfield 55% voted liberal (vs 45% conservative),
61% of the population are college educated,
15% are in the bottom national income quintile,
33% in the second quintile, etc.

As @Peter Flom says, the simplest approach would be to estimate the median (or mean) income for each city, and include that as a control variable in a regression model (using OLS for simplicity, although GLM would be more appropriate): `percent_liberal ~ percent_educated + median_income`. However, this ignores some potentially useful information about the income distribution.

An arguably stronger approach is to assume that income follows a log-normal distribution, estimate the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of this distribution for each city from the quintile data, reflecting median income and income inequality, and including both of these as control variables. $\sigma$  could be replaced with the [Gini coefficient](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4963343/) here, $2\Phi(\sigma / \sqrt{2}) - 1$, which is arguably a better measure of inequality.

If the assumption that income is log-normally distributed is correct, I believe this approach uses all of the information that is available from the quintiles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to control for confounders in the analysis. Define income bands and carry out the analysis for each band separately. Ideally, each band would only be a line, i.e. you set the confounder to one particular value and do your correlation analysis with this fixed confounder. But it seems your data is not rich enough for this to be possible.

Comment: This isn't possible with the data given. We know that 55% of people in Springfield voted liberal, and we know that 15% of people in Springfield are in the bottom income quintile, but we don't know what proportion of the people in Springfield who are in the bottom income quintile voted liberal.